# Java: Program Won't Call my Method

Tags: java, file, methods, directory

I am having a weird problem with my program which is supposed to copy the directory and it's contents that the user will input and then bring the same directory to another directory. The problem I am having is that the program will indeed copy the folder and move it but it won't copy the contents and move them...I have noticed that the program does not call the copyFile method for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Here is my full code:

```
package directcopy;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DirectCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    //Create a new instance of scanner to get user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Ask user to input the directory to be copied
    System.out.print("Input directory to be copied.");

    //Save input as String
    String directoryName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Ask user to input destination where direction will be copied
    System.out.print("Input destination directory will be moved to.");

    //Save input as String
    String destinationName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Run method to determine if it is a directory or file
    isDirFile(directoryName, destinationName);


}//end main

public static void isDirFile (String source, String destination) throws Exception{
    //Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
    //as source directory
    File dirFile = new File (destination, new File(source).getName());

    //Make the new directory
    dirFile.mkdirs();

    //Create an array of File class objects for each item in the source
    //directory
    File[] entries; 

    //If source directory exists
    if (dirFile.exists()){

        //If the source directory is a directory
        if (dirFile.isDirectory()){

            //Get the data and load the array
            entries = dirFile.listFiles();

            //Iterate the array using alternate for statement
            for (File entry : entries){
                if (entry.isFile()){
                    copyFile(entry.getAbsolutePath(), destination);
                } //end if
                else {
                    isDirFile(entry.getAbsolutePath(), destination);
                }  //end else if
            }//end for
        }//end if
    }//end if
    else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    } //end else
}



public static void copyFile (String source, String destination) throws Exception {

    //declare Files
    File sourceFile = null;
    File destFile = null;

    //declare stream variables
    FileInputStream sourceStream = null;
    FileOutputStream destStream = null;

    //declare buffering variables
    BufferedInputStream bufferedSource = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedDest = null;

    try {
        //Create File objects for source and destination files
        sourceFile = new File (source);
        destFile = new File (destination);

        //Create file streams for the source and destination
        sourceStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        destStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

        //Buffer the file streams with a buffer size of 8k
        bufferedSource = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream);
        bufferedDest = new BufferedOutputStream(destStream);

        //Use an integer to transfer data between files
        int transfer;

        //Alert user as to what is happening
        System.out.println("Beginning file copy:");
        System.out.println("\tcopying " + source);
        System.out.println("\tto      " + destination);

        //Read a byte while checking for End of File (EOF)
        while ((transfer = bufferedSource.read()) !=-1){

        //Write a byte
        bufferedDest.write(transfer);
    }//end while

    }//end try

    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An unexpected I/O error occurred.");
    }//end catch

    finally {
        //close file streams
        if (bufferedSource != null)
            bufferedSource.close();

        if (bufferedDest != null)
            bufferedDest.close();

        System.out.println("Your files have been copied correctly and "
                + "closed.");
    }//end finally
}//end copyDir

}//end class
```

Comment: hi this appears to be bigger then it is supposed ti be .. have a look here http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/

Comment: You could debug your code and find out why it is not entering into your method.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'isDirFile' method, 'dirFile' points to the destination directory, which presumably is empty in your tests. The code comments suggest it was intended to be scanning the 'source' directory, but it's actually scanning the *destination*.